# Is it possible to filter TCP retranmission packet in tcpdump?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I am trying to see TCP retransmission packet in tcpdump.

I find commands to filter sync packet, ACK packet but could not able to find filter of retransmitted packet

Is there any command for filter such packets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I've just been using this for tracing re transmissions in wireshark:

```
tcp.analysis.retransmission
```

This also is useful:

```
tcp.flags.reset==1
```

In tcpdump, you can do resets with this expression (not tried re-transmissions yet, but if I figure that out I'll reply to my answer):

```
'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-rst) != 0'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Wireshark or TShark you can use a [display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html):
field name: tcp.analysis.retransmission

AFAIK there is no capture filter to do the trick on tcpdump, dumpcap, Wireshark or TShark.